# UICollectionView Won't Load

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I updated my Xcode to 9 and using iOS 11 for the Base SDK.  Somehow, something got changed when I did this.  Ever since then, the Collection View in my app does not show.  The NSLog never shows in the console for the number of items in section, the NSLog never fires anything in the console when I put in an NSLog for cellForItem either. Everything is wired up properly for it in XIB, and again, this is for an app that already exists in the AppStore, where I changed nothing in code, other than downloading the new Xcode.  What in the world is going on?  Here is the code for it:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES];

    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     arryData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"AIMCON", @"Devotional Songs", @"Saved Devotionals", @"AIM Series 2017", @"Resources", @"Podcasts", @"Website", @"Links",  nil];
    CALayer * l = [viewofimage layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:11];
    [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);


        [self.collectionView registerClass:[CVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    self.collectionView.delegate = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}





    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
        return 1;
        NSLog(@"1");
    }
    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [arryData count];
        NSLog(@"2");
    }

    -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSLog(@"Selected");
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            DevoSongs *dvController = [[DevoSongs alloc] initWithNibName:@"DevoSongs" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
            [dvController release];
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            ListOfDevos *dvController7 = [[ListOfDevos alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListOfDevos" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController7 animated:YES];
            [dvController7 release];

        }
        if (indexPath.row == 4) {
            AIMProject *dvController7 = [[AIMProject alloc] initWithNibName:@"AIMProject" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController7 animated:YES];
            [dvController7 release];

        }
        if (indexPath.row == 5) {
            Podcasts *dvController2 = [[Podcasts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Podcasts" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController2 animated:YES];
            [dvController2 release];

        }
        if (indexPath.row == 6) {
            FamilyMinistry *dvController5 = [[FamilyMinistry alloc] initWithNibName:@"FamilyMinistry" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController5 animated:YES];
            [dvController5 release];

        }
        if (indexPath.row == 7) {
            LinksViewController *dvController6 = [[LinksViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LinksViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController6 animated:YES];
            [dvController6 release];
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            NSLog(@"TABLE");
            SECTable *dvController7 = [[SECTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"SECTable" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController7 animated:YES];
            [dvController7 release];
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            NSLog(@"AIM Series");
            AIMSeries *dvController9 = [[AIMSeries alloc] initWithNibName:@"AIMSeries" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController9 animated:YES];
            [dvController9 release];
        }

    }
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

        CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        NSString *thearticleImage = [[arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
        [cell.theimage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:thearticleImage]];
        //titleLabel2.text = entry.articleTitle;

        CALayer * l = [cell.theimage layer];
        [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
         [l setCornerRadius:11];
        [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
        [cell.labels setText:[arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSLog(@"%@", cell.labels.text);




        return cell;
    }

    @end
```

Here's the difference from when it was working, to now, and all I did was update Xcode.
Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: Look for deprecated collection view delegate methods.

Comment: @tomato I reinstalled Xcode 8 and it wasn’t loading the collection view there either so something must have got changed without me realizing it but as to what I am clueless.

Comment: Not Xcode 9? For what reason, do you reinstall Xcode 8?

Comment: @ElTomato Originally, I thought the issue was related to iOS 11 or Xcode 9.  So, I installed Xcode 8 to confirm.  However, it still was having issues in Xcode 8 with iOS 10 as Base SDK, so clearly, my original thought was wrong, and something unintentionally got changed.

Comment: Plez try to declare arrayData as `@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *arrayData;` and use it as `self.arrayData`

Comment: @Torongo This did not make a difference, either.

Comment: I have tried changing the backgroundColor of the Collection View in both code AND in the XIB file, but on screen it still appears black, so I don't even know if the collection view is showing up on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Set collection view's isPrefetchingEnabled property to false.

Comment: That property was already deselected in the xib file for that.

Comment: I have tried changing the backgroundColor of the Collection View in both code AND in the XIB file, but on screen it still appears black, so I don't even know if the collection view is showing up on screen.